# Disocrd.js play an audio file errors

Tags: node.js, npm, ffmpeg, discord.js

Hi everyone I wanted to ask if any of you could solve the following problem:
I wanted to fail audio in a voice channel but I can't, I managed to connect to the channel but when I have to run the audio file crashes
When I install the modules it gives me the following errors:

````
> ffmpeg-static@4.4.0 install C:\Discord\Jawsbot\node_modules\ffmpeg-static
> node install.js

Downloading ffmpeg 4.4 [||||||||||||||||||||] 100% 0.0s
Failed to download the ffmpeg README.
npm WARN jawsbot@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN jawsbot@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ ffmpeg-static@4.4.0
added 15 packages from 44 contributors, updated 29 packages and audited 44 packages in 7.985s
found 6 vulnerabilities (2 low, 1 moderate, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

C:\Discord\Jawsbot>npm install @discordjs/opus

> @discordjs/opus@0.5.3 install C:\Discord\Jawsbot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[@discordjs/opus] Success: "C:\Discord\Jawsbot\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v83-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\opus.node" is installed via remote
npm WARN jawsbot@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN jawsbot@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ @discordjs/opus@0.5.3
added 45 packages from 90 contributors and audited 89 packages in 20.077s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 6 vulnerabilities (2 low, 1 moderate, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

C:\Discord\Jawsbot>npm install opusscript
npm WARN jawsbot@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN jawsbot@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ opusscript@0.0.8
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 90 packages in 1.316s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show us your code?

Comment: I don’t see any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that instead of channel I had to put connection.play, but now the bot enters and does nothing does not even give an error the piece of code to run the file is as follows:

```
var channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("842859974324518913")
if (!channel) return console.error("The channel does not exist!");
channel.join().then(connection => {
    const dispatcher = connection.play('./audios/private.mp3');
    dispatcher.on("end", end => {
        channel.leave();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These are just warnings. Not errors. There is no need to be alarmed, in the future if you see these warnings just know, 99% of the time ignore them and you should be fine.